# LinkedIn API PHP

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am getting this weird error when trying to authenticate a user with the LinkedIn API.  A var_dump() of the data shows this:

```
string(156) "{"error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : ssl required","error":"invalid_request"}"
```

I am not sure why this is happening can anyone help me out on this issue.

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id'     => $account['linkedin']['api_key'],
        'client_secret' => $account['linkedin']['api_secret'],
        'code'          => $_GET['code'],
        'redirect_uri'  => get_admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=' . self::$accounts_dashboard_page . '&linkedin=authorization&account=' . urlencode($account['id']),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error too but I got it work changing the way of sending the parameters. Instead of and array I sent them like a typical QUERY_STRING.

I mean:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=XXXXXXX&client_secret=ZZZZZZZ&code=YYYYY&redirect_uri=/path/to/your/redirect/uri')
```

I don't know why, but it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";
$header = array( "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );

    $data = http_build_query( array(
        "client_id" => {client_id}',
        "client_secret" => {client_secret},
        "redirect_uri" => {redirect_uri},
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "code" =>$_GET['code']
    ));

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    if( $header !== 0 ){
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    if( $data !== 0 ){
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    $respo = json_decode($response);

echo     $accesstoken = $respo->access_token;
```